# Replace "0x" in hexadecimal string to "\x" in C

Tags: c, hex

I have a C library that requires hexadecimal input of the form "\xFF". I need to pass an array of hexadecimal values formatted as "0xFF" form. Is there a way to replace "0x" by "\x" in C?

Comment: Did you try anything yet?

Comment: If you do `replace "0x" by "\x"` then the value is no longer hexa decimal!. But if you have these values in the form of string, it is valid!

Comment: @OliCharlesworth I tried using : `sprintf(str2,"\\x%x",str1 & 0xFF);`, but this did not help.

Comment: How about `str1[0] = '\\'`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That sounds like an easy string replacement operation, but I think that's not really what you need.

The notation "\xFF" in a C string means "this string contains the character whose encoded value is 0xFF, i.e. 255 decimal".

So if that's what you mean, then you need to do the compiler's job and replace the incoming "0xFF" text with the single character that has the code 0xFF.

There is no standard function for this, since it's typically done by the compiler.

To implement this, I would write a loop that looks for `0x`, and every time it's found, use `strtoul()` to attempt to convert a number at that location. If the number is too long (i.e. 0xDEAD) you need to figure out how to handle that.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. `strtoul()` helped. Used the following (say `hexString` is the string containing the hex value): `const char charValue = (const char) strtol( &(hexString[0]), NULL, 16);`

Answer (score 1):

You can use [strstr](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/strstr.html) in order to find the substring `"0x"` and then replace `'0'` with `'\\'`:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void)
{
    char s[] = "0x01,0x0a,0x0f";
    char *p = s;

    printf("%s\n", s);
    while (p) {
        p = strstr(p, "0x");
        if (p) *p = '\\';
    }
    printf("%s\n", s);
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
0x01,0x0a,0x0f
\x01,\x0a,\x0f
```

But as pointed out by @unwind and @Sathish, that's probably not what you need.